# google apps script shuffle row option code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Does anyone know what is the code for "shuffle row option" in google apps script for google form?

I know it can be done with just clicking on the form itself but if i want to program, what code would that be?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to be?  This will shuffle rows. But you could do it a lot of ways.

```
function shuffleRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  vA.sort(function(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*lr)-Math.floor(Math.random()*lr);
  });
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: i dont mean it in the spreadsheet, i mean it directly on the google form..
like if you create directly on google form, there is a function that says "shuffle row option" when you click on the 3 dots. what im looking for is what is the code to type into google apps script to replicate the exact same thing cause now after typing out my question, i have to manually go to the form and click "shuffle row options".

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you wanted.  I don't use Google Forms very much so I don't know much about it.  I prefer using webapps for my forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the order of the questions using the setShuffleQuestions function [1]:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('[FORM-ID]');
form.setShuffleQuestions();
```

But there's no way to programmatically activate the "shuffle row" option for a dropdown, multiplechoice or checkboxes question.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setshufflequestionsshuffle